# I have a powershell script that counts how many times words appear. How can i show on which lines every word is situated?

Tags: powershell, scripting

So this script counts how many times words appear in the whole file.
Which works perfect.
Now I need it to show on which lines every word above 4 characters appears.
The problem is that I have almost no experience in scripting.

Credits to AdminOfThings for providing me with the current code!

```
Function AnalyseTo-Doc
{
    param ([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$Pad )

    New-Item C:\destination.txt -ItemType file
    $destination = "C:\destination.txt"
    $filecontents = Get-Content $Pad -Raw

    $words = ($filecontents | Select-String -Pattern "\b[A-Za-z]{4,}\b" -AllMatches).Matches.Value
    $words | Group-Object -NoElement | Foreach-Object {
        ("{0},{1}" -f $_.Count,$_.Name) | Add-Content -Path $destination
        }
}
AnalyseTo-Doc
```

Comment: SO is not a free code-(re)writing service. What have you tried to make the code do what you want? What *exactly* doesn't work the way you expected?

Comment: Well, the part that doesn't work, doesn't exist yet. The question exactly is: "How can i show which words appear on every line of a text file". I can't seem to find similar scripts or questions so that's why i asked it here.

Comment: Take a closer look at the data `Select-String` produces (use `Format-List *` or `Get-Member`), and then think about how that information could be used for what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As AnsgarWiechers hinted, Select-String returns a structured object with Matches per Lines.

```
## Q:\Test\2019\06\11\SO_56543125.ps1
Function AnalyseTo-Doc{
    param ([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$Pad )

    $Lines = Select-String -Path $Pad -Pattern '\b[A-Za-z]{4,}\b' -AllMatches
    $Words = ForEach($Line in $Lines){
        ForEach($Match in $Line.Matches){
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                LineNumber = $Line.LineNumber
                Word       = $Match.Value
            }
        }
    }
    $Words | Group-Object Word | ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Count= $_.Count
            Word = $_.Name
            Line = $_.Group.LineNumber -join ','
        }
    }
}

AnalyseTo-Doc Question_SO_56543125.txt
```

With your question text in file `Question_SO_56543125.txt` the script returns:

```
> Q:\Test\2019\06\11\SO_56543125.ps1

Count Word          Line
----- ----          ----
    1 this          1
    1 script        1
    1 counts        1
    1 many          1
    1 times         1
    1 words         1
    1 appear        1
    1 whole         1
    1 file          1
    2 Which         2,3
    1 works         2
...snip...
```

The output can easily be saved in a (csv) file.

Answer (score 0):

Below I'll give you an example of how your problem can be solved:

```
$s = "aaa", "bbb", "ccc" 

$findings = $s | select-string "bbb" 

$valAndLinenumber = $findings | Select-Object @{ l="Value"; e={ $_.matches.value}}, linenumber, line

$valAndLinenumber
```

Output:

```
 Value LineNumber Line
  ----- ---------- ----
  bbb            2 bbb
```

Adaptions to make it work with your script are up to you.

You can find the example under this [link](https://tio.run/##bczBCsIwEATQe79iWXKs/QEJ6F3wIHgtSbrayDZKktZD22@PCYWePA0Mb@bz/pIPPTGnJAJIQKUU1oBa6xLGGISqEg/rOuueRWS2QCAmEw8h@txuurBJ8dl1F@vIjYMmX/g@XeC2ra76lQNOM7DEu@KR8AgkZxBtM6hoegrNVOp1rYH3sz//VUo/).

Further reading:

- [Select-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-6)
- [Calculated property](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2017/01/19/using-powershell-calculated-properties.aspx?m=1)

Comment: With the parameter `-AllMatches` Select-Strings behaves differently, check with a more complex input.

Answer (score 0):

The following modifications should achieve what you want.

```
Function AnalyseTo-Doc
{
    param ([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$Pad )

    New-Item C:\destination.txt -ItemType file
    $destination = "C:\destination.txt"
    $filecontents = Get-Content $Pad

    $words = $filecontents | Select-String -Pattern "\b[A-Za-z]{4,}\b" -AllMatches
    $group = $words.Matches.Value | Group-Object -NoElement
    $output = foreach ($word in $group) {
        [pscustomobject]@{Count = $Word.Count
                Word = $word.Name
                Linenumbers = $words.where{$_.Matches.Value -eq $word.Name}.linenumber
              }
    }
    $output | Foreach-Object {
    ("{0},{1},{2}" -f $_.Count,$_.Word,($_.Linenumbers -Join " ")) | Add-Content -Path $Destination
    }

}
```

The line numbers are joined by a space at the end of each line in the output file. You can change the join character by updating the `-Join " "` section.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply. I can't thank you enough for the help.